# How do I automate the repetitive action of applying filters in CSV in Python?

Tags: python, excel

In a nutshell what I want is to be able to:

- select a file thats csv,or anything excel

  - From that file

    - apply a filter on the the selections needed
    - save that applied filter view to a new file xls that just adds "for review" to the file name to the current folder

`

```
# Import the necessary libraries

import openpyxl
import os
import time
import csv

# Define the path to the CSV file

csv_file = "C:/Users/USERNAME//Desktop/filename.csv"

# Open the CSV file and create a reader object

with open(csv_file, "r") as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)

    # Iterate over the rows in the reader
    rows = []
    for row in reader:
        rows.append(row)

# Open the Excel document and create a new worksheet

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Write the rows from the CSV file to the Excel worksheet

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)

# Apply filters to the top row

ws.auto_filter.ref = "A1:Z1"

# Filter column A by "Network Upload Egress" and "Removable Media Egress"

ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(0, \["Network Upload Egress", "Removable Media Egress"\])

# Save a copy of the Excel document with "Evidence Review" added to the file name

new_file = os.path.splitext(excel_file)\[0\] + " Evidence Review.xlsx"

# Display a loading animation while the process is running

print("Processing...")
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(".", end="")

# Save the copy of the Excel document

try:
    wb.save(new_file)
    print("\\nProcess complete!")
except IOError:
    print("Error saving the copy of the Excel document. Make sure you have permission to save files to the specified location.")`
```

Comment: What is your exact question? What is wrong in the shown code (besides some additional `\` characters)? What are the expected and current output for a given input? I feel hard to provide an answer without those informations...

Comment: I have just realized that you are a new user. So, first, welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to improve your question, you should read [ask] to find useful advices. Long story made short, we expect a single question, with a [mre], meaning enough code and data to reproduce your current state. This dramatically helps to provide good answers.

Comment: thanks Serge , still new to Stack Overflow  and I appreciate the help articles. to be honest I was really flustered with spending too much time on this and needed help.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.

import csv

def filter_csv(input_file, output_file, filter_column, filter_value):
with open(input_file, 'r') as in_file, open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
# Create CSV reader and writer
reader = csv.reader(in_file)
writer = csv.writer(out_file)

```
# Find the index of the filter column
header = next(reader)
filter_column_index = header.index(filter_column)

# Write the header row to the output file
writer.writerow(header)

# Iterate through the rows in the input file
for row in reader:
  # If the filter value is in the filter column, write the row to the output file
  if row[filter_column_index] == filter_value:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

## Example usage

filter_csv('input.csv', 'output.csv', 'State', 'CA')